# how to repeat column value in reusable table

Tags: angular

Hi I am using smarttable(i.e reusable table) in our application. where i will send data through settings from one component file and get in reusable in component. Problem is iam not able to bind nested values in dropdown.settings from one component

```
 'columnsettings': [
                {
                    headerName: "First Name",
                    field: "firstName"
                },
                {
                    headerName: "Last Name",
                    field: "lastName"
                },
                {
                    headerName: "Type",
                    field: "petitionType",
                    type: 'dropDown',
                    data: this.getPetitionTypeValues()
                },
                {
                    headerName: "Updated On",
                    field: "lastUpdate",
                    type: 'datePicker'
                },
                {
                    headerName: "Status",
                    field: "status",
                    type: 'dropDown',
                    data: this.statusTypes
                }

            ]
```

in filterComponent i am getting this data :

```
 moreFilters() {
  console.log('moreFilters: %o', this.smartTable.queryParameters.filter);

  // Prepare moreFilterFields information from smartTable.settings
  if (this.moreFilterFields.length === 0) {
    let columnsettings = this.smartTable.settings['columnsettings'];
    let fieldCount = 0, rowCount = 0;
    // Have 3 fields in one object
    for (let column of columnsettings) {
      if (fieldCount === 3) {
        fieldCount = 0;
        rowCount++;
      }
      if (fieldCount === 0) {
        this.moreFilterFields[rowCount] = [];
      }
      this.moreFilterFields[rowCount][fieldCount] = {};
      this.moreFilterFields[rowCount][fieldCount]['field'] = column['field'];
      this.moreFilterFields[rowCount][fieldCount]['headerName'] = column['headerName'];
      this.moreFilterFields[rowCount][fieldCount]['type'] = column['type'];
      this.moreFilterFields[rowCount][fieldCount]['data'] = column['data'];
      console.log(this.moreFilterFields[rowCount][fieldCount]['data'])
      fieldCount++;
    }
  }

this.dialogService.addDialog(FilterComponent, {
  addMorefilters: true,
  showFilters: false,
  moreFilterFields: this.moreFilterFields,
  smartTable: this.smartTable,
  title: 'More Fiters'
});
```

}

and getting data array also in console.log

in Html i am using like this:

```
<div class='row' *ngFor="let row of moreFilterFields">
                    <div class='col-sm-4' *ngFor="let column of row">
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <label for="filter_{{column['field']}}">{{column['headerName']}}</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="filter_{{column['field']}}" name="filter[{{column['field']}}]" [(ngModel)]="column['value']" size="30" type="text" *ngIf="column['type'] == dropdown "/>

                          <select *ngIf="column['type'] != dropdown " >
                            <option [(ngModel)]="column['value']">{{column['data']}}</option>
                          </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Whole array is binding in array in object form. How to use in dropdown.

Comment: Whats the output of this.getPetitionTypeValues()?

Comment: @VivekDoshi output will be array of objects 0 : {
  display: "H1B",
  value: "H1B"
 }
1 : {
  display: "L1",
  value: "L1"
 }

Comment: @VivekDoshi i want to use that value

Comment: @VivekDoshi can u please look into my new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data will looks like this :

```
0   : { display: "H1B", value: "H1B" } 
1   : { display: "L1", value: "L1" }
```

Change this

```
<select *ngIf="column['type'] != dropdown " >
    <option [(ngModel)]="column['value']">{{column['data']}}</option>
</select>
```

to :

```
<select *ngIf="column['type'] == dropdown " >
    <option *ngFor="let optionData of column['data']" [value] = 'optionData.value'>
        {{ optionData.display }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Please do read more about [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) , [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) , [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

Comment: Hi its working but  with slight change where i have changed <select *ngIf="column['type'] == dropdown " >

Comment: In my question columnsettings I have to  show this dropdown only for status and Type but select tag is appending to datepicker also

Comment: in my application i will have 3 types of input fields text,dropdown and datepicker

Comment: then add conditions for each three of them like `*ngIf="column['type'] == text"` `*ngIf="column['type'] == datepicker "`